# ReactJS: Prevent reordering on array

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here, and apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.

I have the following:

```
const handleTypeCheckboxChangeFood = (event, id, item, bought, packed, name) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
      const filter = foodValue.filter(el => el.id == id ? true : false)
      const filtersaa = foodValue.filter(el => el.id != id ? true : false)
      let olddata;
      filter.map(el => {
        olddata = el
      })
      if (filter.length) {
        if (name == "bought") {
          setFoodValue([...filtersaa, { id, ...olddata, bought: true }])
        } else {
          setFoodValue([...filtersaa, { id, ...olddata, packed: true }])
        }
      } else {
        setFoodValue([...filtersaa, { id, ...item, bought, packed, Quantity: '1' }])
      }
    } else {
      setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState - 1)
      const filtersaa = foodValue.filter(el => el.id == id && el.bought == true && el.packed == true ? true : false)
      const filter = foodValue.filter(el => el.id == id ? true : false)
      let olddata;
      filter.map(el => {
        olddata = el
      })
      const filla = foodValue.filter(v => v.id !== id)
      if (name == "bought") {
        setFoodValue([...filla, { id, ...olddata, bought: false }])
      } else {
        setFoodValue([...filla, { id, ...olddata, packed: false }])
      }
    }

    setTotalAmountF((totalAmountF) => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        totalAmountF = totalAmountF + parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-weight'));
        return totalAmountF
      } else {
        totalAmountF = totalAmountF - parseFloat(event.target.getAttribute('data-weight'));
        return totalAmountF
      }
    });
  }
```

And, the checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
key={`cb-${index}`}
name={checkbox.Name}
value={(checkbox.Name)}
checked={category.length || both.length ? true : false}
id={checkbox.Category}
color="primary"
onChange={(e) => handleTypeCheckboxChangeFood(e, checkbox.id, checkbox, true, false, "bought")}
inputProps={{ "data-weight": checkbox.Weight }}
/>
```

When I click the checkbox, it orders by bought (false first, and then true) ... how do I stop this from automatically reordering the display? The data is in a table and causes the rows to automatically sort according to this value.

Comment: It doesn't sort the table, it sorts the array. The table just rerenders whenever the array is updated. That's how react is supposed to work. If you don't want that to happen, then clone the array and use the original for displaying data, while using the clone for sorting.

Comment: I actually dont need it sorted at all ... it renders within a table that the user clicks checkboxes for within the row